# Rest API C# - how is it possible to pass Stream argument

Tags: c#, json, rest, stream

I need to call the following REST API

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
UriTemplate = "/{subscriptionId}/servers?op=ChangeSubscription")]
Stream ChangeAllServersSubscription(string subscriptionId, Stream requestStream);
```

How can I create and pass `Stream requestStream`?
The stream will contain JSON formatted string

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: What does this stream need to contain? we need some more details on what you're trying to do

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It should contain JSON formatted string

Comment: A formatted string inside a Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before making use of any kind of `Stream`, you should ask the API supplier which stream he's expecting to receive.

Here's an example using a `MemoryStream`, after you create your JSON:

```
// Random objects, just to make the code clear
var myObject = new {Name = "Yakov"};
var myId = "1";
var myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

// Create a MemoryStream (Encoding should be as needed)
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myJson));

// Call your code
var responseStream = ChangeAllServersSubscription(myId, memoryStream);

// And dispose the MemoryStream after you're done.
memoryStream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `HttpWebRequest` on the client side, set the url to point to your service, set appropriate method- in your case `POST`. For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://server/id/servers?op=ChangeSubscription");
request.Method = "POST";
```

Then use `GetRequestStream()` to get the stream on the client side, write your json into this stream, close the stream, then execute the request by calling `GetResponse()`.

```
    Stream stream= request.GetRequestStream();
    //stream.Write write contents of your file here!
    stream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response= (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    //process the response from server
```

If everything went right your web service will get hit and receive your file.